# AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.CaptureOutput not called in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone please advise why [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835920/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate-captureoutput-not-called) works? I have same question using Swift, when I define my 'Scanner' in a standalone swift file, the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.CaptureOutput not called but, when I move the Scanner in the same file when I call session.addOutput(videoOutput) and videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate it works.

I am binginer to Swift/iOS dev, this issue drives me crazy, finally this solution works. thank you for sharing this!

just clarify and add my code:

1. I have a CamService.swift which I have a method to setup the AVCaptureSession:

   session.beginConfiguration()

   // ...

   //add AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

   if session.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
   session.addOutput(videoOutput)

   videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
   videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive) )
   videoOutput.connections.first?.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
   } else {
   //fatalError("could not add video output")
   print("Couldn't add video output to the session.")
   session.commitConfiguration()
   return
   }

   // ...

   session.commitConfiguration()
2. when I extension CamService as below, it works, the  captureOutput can be called

   extension CamService: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
   public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
   didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection:
   AVCaptureConnection) {
   print("sampleBuffer")
   }
   }

But, if I create a new swift file say,

```
MyDalegate: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate,
```

and config

```
videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(MyDalegate(), 
queue:DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive) )
```

this won't work captureOutput never get called.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @Claudio This looks to me like they are asking for an explanation of how the code they linked works, but I do agree it should be clarified.